# Should I include a junction table with a primary key in my ski rental database schema?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, junction-table

I need to make the ER diagram and the relational schema of the Ski rentals. I have an `Customer`, `Rental` and `Ski` as a entities as well as their attributes. `Customers` and `Rentals` should have the one-to-many relationship and the relationship between `Rentals` and `Ski` should be many-to-many (one rental can have many skis and one ski can be rented to many customers). As I did some research on how to make the relational schema, I found out that it is mandatory to make the junction table `Rentals_skis` that include foreign keys from the `Rentals` and `Ski`. Is it necessary to add primary key to the junction table? Also, should I add new entity `Rentals_skis` in my ER diagram?

This is the links to my diagrams that I made using Dia.

Relational schema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LJH0.jpg

ER diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv4b7.jpg

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL.

Comment: I think that the same ski should not be rented to more than 1 person at any given time - even though it can be rented to multiple persons throughout the day. So you will have rows in your RENTALS table with time periods - plus the corresponding foreign keys for the ski unique item ID and for the corresponding person.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for a m:n relationship you need to create the junction table that holds the primary key from each of the entities, e.g. {rental_id, ski_id}, and yes, it should be in your ER diagram.  It might not be in a conceptual model, but it should definitely be in your logical model.

Whether or not you make those two foreign keys together into a composite primary key, or you add a surrogate key (e.g. rental_ski_id) is a design choice and up to you, but the table should have a primary key.

IMO your table names should all be singular nouns (rental, ski, rental_ski) rather than plural nouns (rentals, skis, rentals_skis).